# Robot framework close browser popup window

Tags: html, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I click on a link on a webpage in my application and a new window pops up (I'm using Internet Explorer 11, and not permitted to use any other browser).

The window is opened as an html page from the code: `href=fileName.html`.

However, none of the Robot framework Selenium2Library keywords will close the popped up window, such as `Close Window`, which according to the documentation, says, "Closes the currently open pop-up window". However, this command closes the *main* browser window and NOT the one that popped up.

I also tried using the variants of the `Get Window`  command such as `Get Window Titles` or `Get Window Identifiers`, but it returned either the main browser window or no windows.

Is there a way to close popped up window?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Here is the html link for the window:

```
<a title="Birth Proof Code More Information" id="uef-help0" href="birthProofHelp.html" target="_blank" rel="help" data-uefid="uef-li-hlp" data-modal-disable="true">More Info</a>
```

Here is the source code for the window:

```
!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Birth Proof</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    </head>
    <body>
        A - ALLEGED<br>
        B - BIRTH/BAPTISMAL CERTIFICATE (BEFORE THE AGE OF 5)  / PREFERRED BIRTH PROOF<br>
        C - DEFINITION OF 'CONVINCING EVIDENCE' MET<br>
        F -  PREVIOUSLY ESTABLISHED BY THE SSA<br>
        Q - ESTABLISHED BASED ON EVIDENCE OTHER THAN THAT COVERED UNDER CODES 'B' AND 'C'<br>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried sleeping 60 seconds for the window to appear, and it still didn't work.

The window is really appearing. Like I said, `Close Window` closes the main browser window and NOT the one that popped up.

According to Robot documentation, `Get Window Titles` does this:

> Returns the titles of ALL windows known to the current browser instance.

Comment: `href=fileName.html` by itself won't cause a new window to open up. Can you show the _exact_ definition of the window. When you've tried `close window`, did you wait for a moment to get the window a chance to appear? Are you certain the window is appearing? if `Get window titles` and `get window identifiers` returns only the main window, it seems like this popup window isn't appearing.

Comment: @BryanOakley Please see the edit in my OP

Answer (score 0):

java.awt.robot is an option if all else fails. Use the windows shortcut to close a window: ctrl+w.

EDIT: Adding how to focus the window first (I've been using this for a while and it's working for me, I think I originally got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35393786/java-jna-focus-a-specific-window), answer from @Avinash Jha):

```
    import com.sun.jna.Native;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
    import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions;

    ...

    public interface User32 extends W32APIOptions {
        User32 instance = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class, DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
        boolean ShowWindow(HWND hWnd, int nCmdShow);
        boolean SetForegroundWindow(HWND hWnd);
        HWND FindWindow(String title);
        int SW_SHOW = 1;
    }

    ...

    User32 user32 = User32.instance;
    HWND hWnd = user32.FindWindow("window title");
    user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, User32.SW_SHOW);
    user32.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
```

Then the robot part should be something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;

...

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Comment: But how do I actually select that window to close in the first place? That is the problem.