# Bring an already running java program to the foreground

Tags: java, windows, foreground

I have these two independent java programs running on Windows, let's call the first `program A` and the second `program B`

My objective is to: *bring the already running B program to the foreground by clicking an icon from the A program*.

Keep in mind these programs are completely separate.

I've searched high and low for answers. I've tried to run the program using its `PID` hoping that it would bring the program to the front but I had no luck with that either.

I know there's a way but how can I achieve this using java?

Comment: If this was on a \*NIX machine, I'd suggest using the PID and calling `fg` through system process handling classes, something like [this](https://crunchify.com/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-processes-with-java/) or [this](https://dzone.com/articles/jdk-10-accessing-java-applications-process-id-from).

Comment: I came across that solution for UNIX machines and I searched for an alternative for Windows but couldn't fine one.

Comment: It's a good idea to add a "What I've tried" section to your question, something along the lines of "I had a look at this link, but that only works on UNIX systems. I had a look at this other link, but ..." It'll aid other users in answering your question.

Comment: I thought of doing that but I've looked at countless links and I wanted to keep the question simple and short. Also I specifically said "running on Windows" because I know there would be ambiguity if I hadn't stated that . If I can find the links I'll post them,thank you for your input.

Comment: `SetForegroundWindow`.

Comment: Have you looked at these? [JNA: Focus a specific Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35393786/java-jna-focus-a-specific-window); [`FindWindow()`, `ShowWindow()`, `SetForeGroundWindow()`](https://coderanch.com/t/562454/java/FindWindow-ShowWindow-SetForegroundWindow-effect-win) [How to Bring Window to Top](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/76427/How-to-bring-window-to-top-with-SetForegroundWindo); [Using SetForegroundWindow on Windows Owned by Other Processes](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/42563) ...

Comment: ... [Why does Win32 API (setForegroundWindow) not work on some Child windows?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/16ec27a3-1776-45e9-bd0e-4cd6212eba5f/why-does-win32-api-setforegroundwindow-not-work-on-some-child-windows?forum=windowssdk); [Detect if a program is running with JNA](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-detect-if-a-program-is-running-using-jna.html)